# Is there any difference between `new object()` and `new {}` in c#?

Tags: c#, syntax, anonymous-types

in c#,

```
var x = new {};
```

declares an anonymous type with no properties. Is this any different from

```
var x = new object();
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Difference Between \`new object()\` and \`new {}\` in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586525/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-new-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the types used are different. You can tell this at compile-time:

```
var x = new {};
// Won't compile - no implicit conversion from object to the anonymous type
x = new object();
```

If you're asking whether `new{}` is ever *useful* - well, that's a different matter... I can't immediately think of any sensible uses for it.

Comment: "whether new{} is ever useful" this is a good material for another question. :)

Comment: I'm curious, does the anonymous object created by new {} still inherit from System.Object?

Comment: All C# types inherit from System.Object, so yes.

Comment: Strictly speaking, all C# class and struct types inherit from (or are identical to) object. Interface types are convertible to object but do not inherit from object. Type parameter types are convertible to their effective base class, which always inherits from (or is identical to) object. Pointer types neither inherit from nor are convertible to object.

Comment: `new{}` is great: it's far more compact than `new object()`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, for starters, object is an actual, non-anonymous type...if you do x.GetType() on the 2nd example, you'll get back System.Object.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the return from GetType as mentioned, x would not be of type object, so you would not be able to assign an object type to that variable.

```
        var x = new { };
        var y = new object();

        //x = y; //not allowed
        y = x; //allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's answer was mostly what I wanted, but for the sake of completeness here are some more differences, gained from reflector:

`new {}` overrides three methods of `object` :

1. `Equals` - as mentioned in other answers, `new object` and `new {}` have different types, so they are not equal.
2. `GetHashCode` returns 0 for `new {}` (but why would you put it in a hash table anyway?)
3. `ToString` prints "{}" for `new {}`

Unfortunately I can't think of a practical application for all this. I was just curious.